# Dynamic Object .NET

Tags: .net, dynamic, object

I am facing an interesting problem right now. 
I know it is not that pretty but I have to cope with it anyway.

I am calling a webservice that returns (array of string) something like that (by index)
0 - Table Name ("Employees")
1 - List of all fields returned ("Id, Name, Birthdate")
2 - First field value ("1")
3 - Second field value ("Bobby")
4 - Third field value ("1970-01-01")

What I would like to accomplish is to create a object name after the index 0, having all the strings in the index 1 being all the properties and feed them with their proper value.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I have started reading about the ExpandoObject but before going too far I would like to hear your take on this.

Regards

EDIT: I will have quite a few different tables to fetch the data from, that is what is causing me the problem.

Comment: are you sure you want to use ExpandoObject for this?

Comment: not at all! I am just investigating right now

Comment: I'm not too keen on using a dynamic object from a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use-case but I doubt that `dynamic` is the way to go here. I would just have a `name-value` collection like so:

```
class Result {
    Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string this[string name] {
        get {
            return this.values[name];
        }
        set {
            this.values[name] = value;
        }
    }

    // some details
}
```

Then you can populate the values from the webservice and query the values by saying

```
Result result = PopulateResultFromWebservice();
string id = result["Id"];
```

etc. If you knew the types you could make this indexer of type `object` instead and parse the values to their appropriate type and store them as those typed objects.

The issue with `dynamic` is that if the names of the fields are an unknown, how are you possibly going to write code that utilizes those fields?

> EDIT: I will have quite a few different tables to fetch the data from, that is what is causing me the problem.

Dude, name-value collection all day every day.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I don't understand. You said that the data is coming from a webservice, not a SQL Server database. You can't use LINQ to SQL unless you are interacting directly with a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

If you recive always different kinds of objects with non-predictable set of fields that using ExpandoObject is a good idea (Take a look on [Clay](http://clay.codeplex.com/) library in this case). In other case you just need to create some types that reflects the structure of your object and then materialize them.

Obviously you can use just a simple dictionary, but Using Dynamic object can give you more power, you decide. Real usage case will allow me to give you a better help.